# How can I download runtime framework 'Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App', version 6.0.0 to Raspberry PI 3b+

Tags: c#, wpf, raspberry-pi

I am trying to get a WPF app. running on PI 3b+, running latest (32 bit) PI-OS. I used instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/iot/deployment).
It seemed to go well, and I get good responses to the following commands (on PI):

[dotnet --version] yields: 6.0.100

[dotnet --list-runtimes] yields Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.0 and Microsoft.NETcore.App 6.0.0

But when I I try to run the app, I get: : "framework 'Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App', version 6.0.0 (arm) was not found". Also " the specified framework can be found at [[this link]](https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?framework=Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App&framework_version=6.0.0&arch=arm&rid=raspian.11-arm). "

On *Windows*, that URL shows a button for "arm64" (but not for arm32).

When I put that URL into browser (*on PI*), it shows a page
that has buttons for Windows, Linux, macOS. When clicking the Linux button I do not get a download to the PI. How can I download the dotNet 6.0 desktop runtime for the 32 bit PI OS installed on my PI

Comment: soo you're asking how to run a **WINDOWS**-Desktop-app on linux?

Comment: Not sure about your requirements but like @FranzGleichmann stated, you are asking something pretty impossible, since your are using Linux as an OS. Maybe you could try and look into [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/tutorials/rpi). Windows IoT Core is windows OS running on a Raspberry PI.

Comment: Use following : https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/6.0

Comment: WPF application run on Windows only regardless of whether the target the .NET Framework, .NET Core or .NET 5/6+.

Answer (score 1):

The *Desktop*-runtime does not exist for linux. .NET applications can only be run on linux (including the Raspberry Pi) when they don't include desktop specific features. In particular, WPF and WinForms are not supported on linux. So any .NET application that has a WPF or WinForms GUI won't run on linux. There are some alternative GUI frameworks for .NET that work on linux, but they require quite a rewrite of the GUI part of whatever application you have there.

Comment: With .NET MAUI you can now run desktop apps on Windows/MacOS/Android/iOS (not sure if it works on Linux though): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/what-is-maui?view=net-maui-7.0

Comment: @JimAho Maui still has no official linux support, unfortunately. And Maui is different from Winforms or WPF, so to port a program to Maui, a considerable effort is required.